# Configurate nginx to work with laravel public folder

Tags: laravel, nginx

Here is my nginx.conf file :

The config file i've made not working and it doesn't go to http://localhost/api
my system is manjaro

```
     ....

    http {
           ....
        server {
                 ....
            }
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;      
    }
```

and my laravel config file is :

```
        server {
            root /srv/tamsam/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            gzip            on;
            gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
            gzip_min_length 1000;



        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        }

            location /storage {
                alias /srv/tamsam/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelapi;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                    
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
                }
            }

            location /api {
                alias /srv/tamsam/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelapi;
            location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            }
            }
            location @laravelapi {
                rewrite /api/(.*)?$ /api/index.php?$is_args$args last;
            }

    }
```

but the http://localhost/api give me the error 404 Not Found

I appreciate your help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `@laravelapi` locations configuration is not correct.

```
location @laravelapi {
  rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php last;

}
```

Please also check your php configuration

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
 }
```

The `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` is important to make it work.

Comment: Now i got error 403 forbiden

Comment: if i set autoindex=on no any more 403 message but doesn't load index.php

Comment: What is in the error_log?

Comment: Actually the error log line was commented out in the nginx.conf file by uncommenting it i end up to troubleshoot the problem.thanks